# Query documents with condition on array field in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
     expenses: [{name: String, cost: number}]
});

schema.virtual('totalCost').get(function() {
    let totalCost = 0;
    this.expenses.forEach((expense)=> {
        totalCost += expense.cost;
    })

    return totalCost;
})
```

Now I want to query all trips that have totalCost between minCost and maxCost. Is there any way I can do that? I tried $where but I can't pass minCost, maxCost to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query against a Mongoose virtual property as they only exist in the Mongoose model representation of documents, not in MongoDB itself where the query should be executed against.

You can however run an aggregation query that calculates the total cost and then use the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline to query the documents. The following example shows this approach:

```
Trip.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$expenses" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "totalCost": { "$sum": "$expenses.cost" },
            "expenses": { "$push": "$expenses" }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "totalCost": {
                "$gte": minCost,
                "$lte": maxCost
            }
        }
    }           
]).exec(callback);
```

Comment: I am actually working on Trip model. :)) Thanks for your answer. I wonder what if I put a totalCost attribute to the schema and update it whenever the expenses change. Is it a better solution in performance? Because I read the document about $unwind, it deconstructs the array into n documents where n is the length of the array field.

Comment: Indeed that would be a better approach as you said, `$unwind` is not as efficient since it produces a cartesian product of the documents i.e. a copy of each document per array entry, which uses more memory (possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory) and therefore takes time to produce as well processing the documents during the flattening process. You would rather have a computed field or a separate attribute that gets updated when an expense changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think $where is the only way, you can achieve that but $where is costly.

I am not sure what are the options in mongoose to use $where but it would be something like below

```
var minCost=1000;
var maxCost = 10000;
query.$where(function () {
  var cost=0;
  for(var i in this.expenses){cost+=this.expenses[i].cost}
  if(cost>minCost && cost<maxCost){return true;}
})
```

Here is the [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-%24where)

Another way is we can pass the javascript as a string in $where clause

```
var minCost=1000;
var maxCost = 10000;
var func = 'var cost=0;for(var i in this.expenses{cost+=this.expenses[i].cost}if(cost>'+minCost+' && cost<'+maxCost+'){return true;}'
query.$where(func);
```

Comment: When I pass minCost and maxCost to the function I got this error: ReferenceError: minCost is not defined :\n_funcs5@:5:1\n'. Can we pass the variable to the function like that?

Comment: honestly, I guess we could have because it's in scope, but in case if you can't there is another way where you can pass the function as a string, but that is more of a trick. would try to update my answer.

Comment: I think it's scope in the source code, I mean the program but not in the context where the query is executed by MongoDB. I pass the javascript as a string and it works. Thank you so much!